# MailChimp - Cannot delete old audience list due to "being used on a published landing page" but there is no published landing page

Tags: mailchimp

Whenever I try to delete an old audience list of ours (the charity I work for) on MailChimp, I get an error message saying the list cannot be deleted because it is being used on a published landing page. However, we don't have any published landing pages. I've gone through and deleted an draft emails pending for this audience, and the only thing which exists now is emails which were already sent. Anyone have any ideas? Any and all help appreciated.[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHlvl.jpg)[image: No published landing pages exist]

Answer (score 1):

Go to campaigns and choose the list that your having a problem with. Then choose ongoing and disable anything thats live. that should do the trick.

Ive also seen reports that the website that you build with mailchimp can be causing this